# Getting System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:'Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallIntMethod'. when integrating Push Notifications in Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to integrate Push Notifications in my Xamarin Android app. I followed the integration steps but I am getting a `System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:'Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallIntMethod'.` Exception at `IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable` I have trying using GCM from Nuget Packages as well as GCM from Components but in both cases I'm getting the same exception.

The following is the method where I get the exception:

```
public bool IsPlayServicesAvailable ()
{
    GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance;
    int resultCode =  googleAPI.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.Success)
    {
        if (googleAPI.IsUserResolvableError (resultCode))
            msgText.Text = googleAPI.GetErrorString (resultCode);
        else
        {
            msgText.Text = "Sorry, this device is not supported";
            Finish ();
        }
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        msgText.Text = "Google Play Services is available.";
        return true;
    }
```

The following is the exception:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallIntMethod'.
  at PushNotificationsEx.MainActivity.IsPlayServicesAvailable () [0x00007] in c:\Users\creatives\Documents\Projects\PushNotificationsEx\PushNotificationsEx\MainActivity.cs:33
  at PushNotificationsEx.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00026] in c:\Users\creatives\Documents\Projects\PushNotificationsEx\PushNotificationsEx\MainActivity.cs:27
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.21-series/49a04b96/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-21/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2380
  at at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.d4b76202-f771-4a49-a7bc-8b296cb1fd19 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x00043>
```

Could you please let me know how to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: The class GoogleApiAvailability is being resolved but the method IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable is not?

Comment: @ArthurThompson Yes. During compile time I don't get any errors but after running the app I get the above exception. Please help.

Comment: what is the dependency you are adding?

Comment: @ArthurThompson I have added the Nuget Package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm(27.0.0.0) and with it the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base(27.0.0.0), Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement(27.0.0.0) and Xamarin.Android.Support.v4(23.0.1.3) Nuget packages got added. I have also tried using older versions of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm like 26.0.0.0 and 25.0.0.0 but still get the same MissingMethodException.